# does copyWithZone on an NSArray call copyWithZone on its elements too?

Tags: cocoa

here's the scenario, I have this array of `Person` objects. `copyWithZone` is implemented on `Person` and works as expected.

I have an array of `Person` objects, however when I create a copy of the array and modify things in original array (change attributes of a `Person`) it changes the copy as well. So my best guess is that when I call `copyWithZone` on `NSArray`, it does not call it on its elements. Please confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed. Cocoa's collection classes implement `NSCopying` by creating a shallow copy. If you need a deep copy, you will have to implement it yourself.